# Docker: Not able to run any command in images built using dockerfile

Tags: docker

Hi i am using  docker version 1.5.0 on ubuntu 14.04. I have a ubuntu and centos official base image from dockerhub. If i run these images I can execute any command in container

```
sudo docker run -it ubuntu /bin/sh
# ls
```

output

```
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

Now when I use this images in my Dockerfile and run that container
 doing `ls` gives me `command not found`

Any idea whats going wrong?

Comment: I got the issue unfortunately I was doing ENV PATH some/path which was removing existing path variables.

Comment: Can you post a sample Dockerfile?